# Campaign Member Sharing Rules

Tags: campaign, sharing-rule, apex-sharing, criteria-based-sharing

I need to create a Sharing Rule that only allows Users to see Campaign Members where they are the record owner of the Contact or Lead that corresponds with the Campaign Member.

Sharing Rules don't support the formula criteria I would be using, and I'm not finding a 'CampaignMemberShare' object that I can reference in apex.

Is there another way I might be able to attack this? Am I missing something? Or am I out of luck on this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

A CampaignMember is a junction object between a Campaign and a member (lead or contact). The CampaignMember sharing settings are controlled by the related Campaign's record much like a master-detail. In short, I don't think you can do what you're trying to do. What's the end goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: for Users to only see the Campaign Members that are associated with Contacts or Leads that they own